# ANSI escape code not working properly [C++]

Tags: c++, ansi-escape

I am using the ANSI escape code to print colored output.

I am getting proper colored output in vs code integrated terminal.
[image]

But when I am running the program in external command-prompt/Powershell, I am not getting the expected colored output.

[image]

My program looks something like this:

```
#define RESET   "\033[0m"
#define RED  "\x1B[31m"
#define GREEN  "\x1B[32m"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 1){
        std::cout << RED ">> Invalid Arguments!" RESET;
    }else{
        if(verify_password()){
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }else{
            std::cout <<  "\n>> " RED "Invalid Password!" RESET;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Complete Code](https://github.com/Aswal-Ashutosh/getpass-cli/blob/main/getpass.cpp)

**NOTE**: One weird thing I observed is that if I am entering the correct password then everything is working fine in both terminals(getting proper colors). But the problem is when either I am entering an incorrect password or an invalid amount of arguments

What might be the reason for this?

**EDIT:** I figured out a way to make it work. I found that in order to make these escape codes work I need to have at least one call to `system()` function. But still, I am not sure how these things are connected.

Comment: Possible answer on sister site: [Windows console with ANSI colors handling](https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling) (not 100% sure if this applies to powershell as well, or only cmd).

Comment: Instead of ANSI escape codes, you may want to use Windows console APIs, like [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute).

Comment: @Eljay actually they should use VT100 codes for forwards compat, but they need to turn on the mode. You can do this with [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#output-sequences)

Comment: There are libraries that understand what escape codes to send to what consoles (as they can all very slightly). NCurses is one such library there are probably more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, consoles on Windows required use of the [console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference) in the Windows SDK in order to do effects like color.  But recent versions of Windows now support escape codes (and even UTF-8), but programs have to opt-in by calling [SetConsoleMode with ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).  (Opting in preserves backward compatibility for older programs that aren't using escape codes or UTF-8.)

If you're getting color in some places and not others, then I'd guess there's a problem related to the state the terminal/console is in when sending the escape codes.  For example, if the terminal thinks it's already processing an escape code and a new one begins, it might not recognize either.  I suppose this might also be a problem if one part of the program uses escape codes but another part uses the Console API.